# Outer join two dataframes, but prevent all possible row combinations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with columns `Customer` and `Location`. In the screenshot and code below, they are labelled `Before` and `After`.

| Before |  | After |  | Desired Output |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer | Location | Customer | Location | Customer | Location Before | Location After | Flag |
| A | 1 | A | 1 | A | 1 | 1 |  |
| B | 1 | B | 2 | B | 1 | 2 | True |
| C | 1 | C | 1 | C | 1 | 1 |  |
| C | 2 | C | 2 | C | 2 | 2 |  |
| D | 3 | D | 3 | D | 3 | 3 |  |
| D | 4 | D | 5 | D | 4 | 5 | True |
| E | 6 | E | 8 | E | 6 | 8 | True |
| E | 7 | E | 9 | E | 7 | 9 | True |
| F | 1 | F | 1 | F | 1 | 1 |  |
| F | 2 | F | 3 | F | 2 |  | True |
| F | 3 |  |  | F | 3 | 3 |  |
| G | 1 | G | 1 | G | 1 | 1 |  |
| G | 2 | G | 4 | G | 2 | 4 | True |
| G | 3 |  |  | G | 3 |  | True |
| H | 1 | H | 5 | H | 1 | 5 | True |
| H | 2 | H | 6 | H | 2 | 6 | True |
| H | 3 |  |  | H | 3 |  | True |
| I | 7 | I | 7 | I | 7 | 7 |  |
| I | 8 | I | 8 | I | 8 | 8 |  |
|  |  | I | 9 | I |  | 9 | True |
| J | 1 | J | 3 | J | 1 | 3 | True |
| J | 2 | J | 4 | J | 2 | 4 | True |
|  |  | J | 5 | J |  | 5 | True |

[image: Desired Output]

Each row represents a "lane" for how a customer is serviced. For example, the `Before` table can be read:

- Customer A has a lane to Location 1
- Customer B has a lane to Location 1
- Customer C has a lane to Location 1
- Customer C has a lane to Location 2

...etc

The business question that I am trying to answer is, from the Customer's perspective, which lanes have changed from Before to After. I would flag the rows by comparing `Facility A` to `Facility B` for each row, flagging when they are not equal.

For lanes that exist in one table but not the other, it doesn't matter how they are paired. i.e. for customer G, it doesn't matter if the `After` location `4` was paired with `2` or with `3`, either option is valid as long as it's reproducible.

It is also important that if the total number of lanes are different between `Before` and `After`, we see that. For example in `Before` customer `H` has 3 lanes, but `After` they have 2. It's important to note that they "lost" a lane.

Essentially, the desired output is a dataframe containing exactly 1 copy of each row of `Before`, and 1 copy of each row of `After`, concatenated so that the [`Customer`, `Location`] values match when possible.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
a = {'Customer':['A','B','C','C','D','D','E','E','F','F','F','G','G','G','H','H','H','I','I','J','J'],
     'Location':[1,1,1,2,3,4,6,7,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,7,8,1,2]}
Before = pd.DataFrame(a)

b = {'Customer':['A','B','C','C','D','D','E','E','F','F','G','G','H','H','I','I','I','J','J','J',],
     'Location':[1,2,1,2,3,5,8,9,1,3,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,4,5]}
After = pd.DataFrame(b)

c = {'Customer':['A','B','C','C','D','D','E','E','F','F','F','G','G','G','H','H','H','I','I','I','J','J','J',],
     'Location A':[1,1,1,2,3,4,6,7,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,7,8,None,1,2,None],
     'Location B':[1,2,1,2,3,5,8,9,1,None,3,1,4,None,5,6,None,7,8,9,3,4,5]}
desired_output = pd.DataFrame(c)
```

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). You could [format it as a table](/editing-help#tables) instead.

Comment: Ok, I'll remake it. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution (assuming there aren't duplicates in customer locations):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest


def fn(g):
    # get the right group from the `g_after` dictionary
    # Note: if the group in `g_after` doesn't exist - handle it appropriately
    a = g_after.get(g["Customer"].iat[0])
    if a is None:
        g["Location Before"] = g["Location"]
        g["Location After"] = np.nan
        g = g.set_index("Location")
        return g

    g["Location Before"] = g["Location"]

    # set index to Location, we use this index to merge the same values from After
    g = g.set_index("Location")
    mask = a["Location"].isin(g["Location Before"])

    # merge the same values from After group
    for l in a.loc[mask, "Location"]:
        g.loc[l, "Location After"] = l

    # merge the rest of values
    # we use `zip_longest` here because the sizes of Before/After could be different
    for i, v in zip_longest(
        g.index[~g.index.isin(a["Location"])], a.loc[~mask, "Location"]
    ):
        if i is None:
            # put the value from After as new row (note, the index `v` doesn't exist in dataframe `g` before - this creates new row)
            g.loc[v, "Location After"] = v
        else:
            # put the value to existing index `i` in dataframe `g`
            g.loc[i, "Location After"] = v

    # the Customer for newly added rows is NaN, so fill them
    g["Customer"] = g["Customer"].ffill().bfill()
    return g

# create a dictionary from `After` dataframe for easy access
g_after = {i: v for i, v in After.groupby("Customer")}

# group `Before` by Customer and use our custom `fn` merge function
out = Before.groupby("Customer", group_keys=False).apply(fn).reset_index(drop=True)
out["Flag"] = out["Location Before"] != out["Location After"]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   Customer  Location Before  Location After   Flag
0         A              1.0             1.0  False
1         B              1.0             2.0   True
2         C              1.0             1.0  False
3         C              2.0             2.0  False
4         D              3.0             3.0  False
5         D              4.0             5.0   True
6         E              6.0             8.0   True
7         E              7.0             9.0   True
8         F              1.0             1.0  False
9         F              2.0             NaN   True
10        F              3.0             3.0  False
11        G              1.0             1.0  False
12        G              2.0             4.0   True
13        G              3.0             NaN   True
14        H              1.0             5.0   True
15        H              2.0             6.0   True
16        H              3.0             NaN   True
17        I              7.0             7.0  False
18        I              8.0             8.0  False
19        I              NaN             9.0   True
20        J              1.0             3.0   True
21        J              2.0             4.0   True
22        J              NaN             5.0   True
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @wjandrea I've added some comments to the code.

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea HOW it works, but looks like it does. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution with [`merge_ordered`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_ordered.html) :

```
C, L = "Customer", "Location"
BF, AF = "Before", "After"

def align(x):
    m1 = x.filter(like=BF).isna().all(axis=1)
    m2 = x.filter(like=AF).isna().all(axis=1)
    gr = (m2.cumsum().where(~m1, m1.cumsum()) if m1.any()&m2.any()
        else x[C].duplicated(keep=False).cumsum())
    return x.groupby(gr).first()

out = (
    pd.merge_ordered(
        Before.rename({L: BF}, axis=1), After.rename({L: AF}, axis=1),
        left_on=BF, right_on=AF, left_by=C, suffixes=(BF, AF)
    ).assign(Flag=lambda x: x.isna().any(axis=1).replace(False, ""))
    .groupby(C, group_keys=False).apply(align).convert_dtypes()
    .reset_index(drop=True)[[C, BF, AF, "Flag"]]
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   Customer  Before  After  Flag
0         A       1      1      
1         B       1      2  True
2         C       1      1      
3         C       2      2      
4         D       3      3      
5         D       4      5  True
6         E       6      8  True
7         E       7      9  True
8         F       1      1      
9         F       2   <NA>  True
10        F       3      3      
11        G       1      1      
12        G       2      4  True
13        G       3   <NA>  True
14        H       1      5  True
15        H       2      6  True
16        H       3   <NA>  True
17        I       7      7      
18        I       8      8      
19        I    <NA>      9  True
20        J       1      3  True
21        J       2      4  True
22        J    <NA>      5  True
```